# Looping though a dictionary containing objects

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary

I have the following loop over a dictionary type collection

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<Vector2, Object> entry in v_map.map_set)
{

}
```

I want to access the object properties, but the expected syntax doesn't work. E.G:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<Vector2, Object> entry in v_map.map_set)
            {
                Object ob = entry.Value;
                ob.property;
            }
```

Fails because C# can't find the property wanted.
So, how do I access the desired properties?

**solution:**

```
  foreach(KeyValuePair<Vector2, Object> entry in v_map.map_set)
            {
                if (entry.Value is warehouse)
                {
                    warehouse ob = (warehouse)entry.Value;

                }
            }
```

Comment: What type to expect the values to be? Can you make the dictionary generic in the value type? If not, you'll have to cast, or you could use `dynamic` if there's no common base type containing the property you need.

Comment: The value will be a range of different objects. I can predict what types of objects, but I need to store them generically to maintain the ke value link correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the type of the objects that are in the KeyValuePair, you can cast it to that type, and you will be able to find the properties you need.

And if you have several different objects stored, you can check which type it is by using `is`. 
Like so:

```
if(entry.Value is Foo)
{
   Foo lFoo = (Foo)entry.Value;
}
else if(entry.Value is Bar)
{
   Bar lBar = (Bar)entry.Value;
}
```

Comment: @tracertong, one thing to remember here is that this solution isn't scalable (*though it may not matter if there aren't a lot of types or the types don't proliferate over time*). One other thing to remember is that if each type has the exact same property name (as Geerten shows in the example), reflection is a much better solution because it would only take a couple of lines of code (*oh and would beg for an Interface so that you could simply cast them to an Interface type, in which case you wouldn't even need reflection*).

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of Refection to get the value of proerty of the object.

something like this

```
PropertyInfo info2 = object.GetType().GetProperty("prpertyname");
Object val = info2.GetValue(object, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using an `object` which isn't typed. So you're going to need to use reflection like this:

```
PropertyInfo pi = ob.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName");
var val = pi.GetValue(ob, null);
```

Now, if the property isn't `public` then you'll need to employ something else like this:

```
PropertyInfo pi = ob.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var val = pi.GetValue(ob, null);
```

Now, if this is actually a ***field*** you're trying to get to, you're going to need to do something different even yet:

```
FieldInfo fi = ob.GetType().GetField("fieldName");
var val = fi.GetValue(ob);
```

[GetProperty method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103.aspx)

[BindingFlags enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx)

[GetField method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ek9c21e.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `entry.Value` to the type you need. The [Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type itself isn't going to expose the properties you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to access the values, and you know the expected type you can use

```
foreach(ExpectedType value in v_map.map_set.Values.OfType<ExpectedType>())
{
    var property = value.Property;
}
```

where `Property` is a property on `ExpectedType`.